# When rendering a page, can't load external resources

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I'm currently trying to generate a PDF document from a HTML page through Node & PhantomJS.

If my page contains local resources, or only static things, it works fine :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="StyleSheet" media="screen" href="./style.css" />
        <link rel="StyleSheet" media="print" href="./print.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The title</h1>
        <p>hai <span class="foo">lol <span class="bar">I'm generating</span> a pdf</span> !</p>
        <p class="centre"><img src="http://www.gratuit-en-ligne.com/telecharger-gratuit-en-ligne/telecharger-image-wallpaper-gratuit/image-wallpaper-animaux/img/images/image-wallpaper-animaux-autruche.jpg" /></p>
        <canvas id="test_canvas" width="200px" height="100px"/>

        <script>
            setTimeout(function () {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('test_canvas').getContext('2d');

                ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
                evt.initEvent('pdfTrigger', true, false);

                document.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So here, the image is correctly rendered, and the stylesheets are also correctly rendered. But if I add an inclusion from a distant image, or a distant script (something beginning with either `//`, either `http://` or `https://`, even if it is directed towards my local environment), the content is not loaded :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="StyleSheet" media="screen" href="./style.css" />
        <link rel="StyleSheet" media="print" href="./print.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The title</h1>
        <p>hai <span class="foo">lol <span class="bar">I'm generating</span> a pdf</span> !</p>
        <p class="centre"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Ostrich,_mouth_open.jpg" /></p>

        <script>
            setTimeout(function () {
                evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
                evt.initEvent('pdfTrigger', true, false);

                document.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The image is not rendered ; if I try with a jQuery include from a cdn and some jQuery code (like firing an event through `$(document).trigger('pdfTrigger')`), it says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`, and thus the event is never fired. If I include it in my html file on a local resource (like `<script src="./jquery.min.css"></script>`), the error disappear but the event is never fired...

Here is the phantomjs script i'm using :

```
/**
 * Render a PDF from an HTML file
 *
 * @author Baptiste Clavié <baptiste@wisembly.com>
 * Adapted from PhantomJs' example "rasterize.js"
 */

var orientation = 'portrait',
    system = require('system'),
    args = system.args.slice(1);

if (args.length < 2 || args.length > 3) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('Usage: rasterize.js source output [orientation]');
    system.stderr.writeLine('   source : html source to put in the pdf');
    system.stderr.writeLine('   output : output when the pdf will be written');
    system.stderr.writeLine('   orientation : document orientation (either portrait or landscape');

    phantom.exit((args.length === 1 & args[0] === '--help') ? 0 : 1);
}

if (typeof args[2] !== 'undefined') {
    if (-1 === ['portrait', 'landscape'].indexOf(args[2])) {
        system.stderr.writeLine('Invalid argument for [orientation]');
        system.stderr.write('Expected either "portrait", either "landscape" ; got "' + args[2] + '"');

        phantom.exit(1);
    }

    orientation = args[2];
}

var page = require('webpage').create(),
    identifier = '___RENDER____';

page.paperSize = { format: 'A4', orientation: orientation, margin: '1cm' };

page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.evaluate(function(identifier) {
        document.addEventListener('pdfTrigger', function () {
            console.log(identifier);
        }, false);
    }, identifier);
};

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    system.stderr.writeLine(msg);

    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        system.stderr.writeLine('   ' + item.file + ':' + item.line);
    });

    phantom.exit(1);
}

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);

    if (msg !== identifier) {
        return;
    }

    page.render(args[1], { format: 'pdf' });
    phantom.exit(0);
}

page.open(args[0], function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        system.stderr.write('Unable to load the file "' + args[0] + '"');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

To launch my script, i'm using the following command : `phantomjs rasterize.pdf test.html test.pdf`

to sum up, it seems I can't load any external things from a html when trying to render it in Phantom, and jQuery is not recognized (and probably some other scripts ?)

Any idea ? If more precision if needed, please don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    evt.initEvent('pdfTrigger', true, false);

    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 3000);
```

To:

```
window.onload = function () {
    evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    evt.initEvent('pdfTrigger', true, false);

    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

The reason why it was failing is because that image is pretty big, and you were triggering the pdf event before the image had been properly downloaded. Using `window.onload` is reliable as the `onload` event will only be run when all page resources have loaded.

Comment: this could do the trick for loading external resources, but now i have another problem which is not really related. Note that the usage of `setTimeout` is here only to mock a "doing things on my webpage", as you can imagine the given html is not really what I want to render. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Then just do `window.onload = function() { setTimeout(function() { /* do stuff, then dispatch the pdf event */ }, 3000); };`

Comment: Yup that is what I had in mind to move on to the next problem. :)